# CMD/Batch Prompting for Input loop without goto command

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, cmd, prompt

I have a loop scanning for the files of a folder and I want to ask for each file if it should be moved or not. As I am already in that loop I can't use goto commands.

**How can I prompt a input loop (yes / no) without using a goto command?**

```bash
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

FOR %%a in (*.jpg) DO (

:: ask
set /p Input="Should !a! be moved? (yes/no)"

if %Input% == 'yes' (
MOVE !a! path/
)

if %Input% == 'no' (
:: just move on in loop
)

:: if not yes or no goback to ask

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this directly because of the way the FOR loop is processed. 
You can do it indirectly though. Look for the call-command:

```bash
echo off
setlocal

for %%i in (*) do
    call :Bar %%i
goto :eof

:Bar  
@echo %1 
goto :eof 


:eof    
endlocal
```

Answer (score 3):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "input="    
    for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
        cmd /v /e /q /c "for /l %%z in (0) do (set /p "input=Should %%a be moved (yes/no^)? " & if /i !input!==yes (exit 0) else if /i !input!==no (exit 1))"
        if not errorlevel 1 (
            echo move "%%a" "c:\somewhere"
        ) else (
            echo skipping %%a
        )
    )
```

A new `cmd` instance is started for each file to retrieve user input. This input is validated and errolevel is used to return user selection to parent code.

While it is not usually a good idea start a new process for each iteration of a loop, in this case, as the user interaction is required for each file, the time needed to start the new `cmd` instance can be ignored as the user itself will require a lot more time.

`move` commands are only echoed to console. If the behaviour is correct, remove the `echo` that prefixes the `move` command.

Comment: getting a syntax error. I used the version from @dlanod-kcud though it uses goto-like commands.

Comment: @user189996, i have copied the posted code, pasted it to a new batch file and executed it without errors. Where do you get the syntax error?

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell can save you a lot of trouble...

```
get-childitem "*.jpg" | foreach-object {
  move-item $_ "path/" -confirm
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

FOR %%a in (*.jpg) DO (

   rem ask
   set /p Input="Should %%a be moved? (yes/no)"

   if "!Input!" == "yes" (
      MOVE %%a path/
   )

)
```

Comment: Yes, this (or something similar) is the way most of us will solve it, but this code misses the `:: if not yes or no goback to ask` part in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is the `choice` command, which accepts only predefined keystrokes, so there is no additional need to check for valid options:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%a in (*.jpg) DO (
  choice /C YN /M "Should %%a be moved? "
  if %errorlevel% == 2 echo not moving
  if %errorlevel% == 1 move "%%a" path\
)
```

for more information, use `choice /?`

(Note: `choice` is not available in some windows versions)